# IBM MQ - Websphere Application Server - MQ Failover

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-9

I have a JEE application (simple EJB application which puts a message to queue) which needs to connect to a uniform cluster queue managers (QMC1, QMC2) and PUT messages. The JEE application runs in a Wepshpere application server,and uses CCDT, with the following commands to consider the queue managers as a group.

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(QMC1.CHL) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) CONNAME('192.168.1.12(9001)') QMNAME(QM) AFFINITY(NONE) TRPTYPE(TCP) REPLACE
DEFINE CHANNEL(QMC2.CHL) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) CONNAME('192.168.1.12(9002)') QMNAME(QM) AFFINITY(NONE) TRPTYPE(TCP) REPLACE
```

I have done the connection factory setting with `*QM` as the queue manager name. Also in the WAS `connection factory -> advanced properties -> Client reconnect options`, I have selected
`RECONNECT`.

My issue is, when both queue managers are running I can put messages to a single the queue,
(I have increased the queue work load rank so that all the messages go to a single queue in the cluster (say QMC1).

But if QMC1 is down, the JEE application is unable to connect to the surviving queue manager (QMC2) as it is trying to re-connect to QMC1, not based on the queue manager group.

Have I misunderstood anything here? Will the `RECONNECT` will try to reconnect to the same queue manager, not the available queue manager based on CCDT?  Shouldn't a uniform cluster queue manager support this fail-over behavior via a CCDT queue manager group?

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: I think you have to set the client  weight also on both ccdt entries.

Comment: Hi Josh, I just went through the IBM doc, isn't CLNTWGHT for load balancing? where if 0 is selected no load balancing is performed? My issue is if one queue manager is down, according to CCDT entries, shouldn't the WAS connection factory config try to connect to the available queue manager, apologies if I'm wrong with any of the above.

Comment: I'm not a JEE expert, but is the bottom of this page relevant here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=environments-enterprise-javabeans-web-based-applications

Comment: I went through that Morag, but the expectation here is to handle re connection at either WAS level or MQ level hence looking for some expert opinion.